# Set a Google Analytics Custom Dimension Value Without Sending an Extra Pageview

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to send a GA Custom Dimension with data that is taken from an API. So the Custom Dimension data will be set after the 'pageview' is sent. So the default code would be:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Set value for custom dimension at index 1.

ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Level 1');

// Send the custom dimension value with a pageview hit.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But in my situation I need to complete the following:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Send the custom dimension value with a pageview hit.
ga('send', 'pageview');

// Load and set value for custom dimension at index 1 from an API
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Level 1');

---> Send the dimension to Google without double counting the pages in GA
```

I know I can setup the code as required in the first example, but I don't want to wait for the API data to load before sending the 'pageview'. So I am looking for a solution to force in the dimension data after.

**EDIT/UPDATE 1:** The "dimensions" need to be shown in the reporting view for standard pageviews in GA.

Comment: Is there a specific reason it has to be sent after the pageview? Seems like whatever API you are using to get the value for `dimension 1` could just be loaded prior to `ga` calls.

Comment: @kevindeleon Yeah, that is a possible option. But there are 2 considerations. 1. Ideally, I would like the pageview to be called ASAP and not wait for the API, so we don't loose the data if the user exits the page. 2. Purely from a coding and speed POV, the dimension code is written, if I can find a valid solution all I need to do is add an extra line to the end.

Comment: Yeah..but the issue is...I don't think you can do this the exact way you're wanting to (sending after the pageview)...not from a "dimension" standpoint anyway...you could set it as a dimension and then fire some type of virtual pageview with a custom url like "/my-custom-url" that you could then setup reports/goals for and it would be available for a dimension in for that pageview...or you could send it as an event like @nyuen said in his answer...but those still wouldn't be available as "dimensions" in your reporting view for your standard pageviews.

Comment: @kevindeleon OK, if it can not be done, then that's still a valid answer. But it doesn't hurt to ask the question ;) Your response was very helpful. I'll actually amend the question in response. I'd actually post your negative answer I think it might be the only logical solution.

Comment: I'll post my answer, and sorry...I didn't mean to sound negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the only way you can accomplish this in the way you seek with the requirements you have (as far as I know), is to load your needed API before you fire your `ga` function calls, and then fire them in the proper order. Set dimension first, then fire pageview call.

Otherwise, I don't think it's possible from a "dimension" standpoint anyway...you could set it as a dimension and then fire some type of virtual pageview with a custom url like "/my-custom-url" that you could then setup reports/goals for and it would be available for a dimension in reports for that pageview...or you could send it as an event like @nyuen said in his answer...but those still wouldn't be available as "dimensions" in your reporting view for your standard pageviews.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to send it with another hit, like a non-interaction event:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'custom dimension', 'set', {nonInteraction: true});
```

but whatever the case, it has to be sent in with a hit.

> Custom dimension or metric data may only be sent with an existing hit.

(cf. [Custom Dimensions and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets))